# Including seasons and months into GLMM: should they be crossed or nested effects?

Tags: r, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have collected data from five consecutive fishing seasons (five factor levels). Each fishing season has five months within (five factor levels). Considering that I have a temporal correlation in my data (fishing season>> month), I thought it was a good idea to implement GLMM. I am attempting to fit a mixed effects model using R and lme4, but I am new to mixed models. 
I'd like to model the response as the probability to observe a fishing event in a day-by-day basis (presence/ absence) as a function of several continuous and categorical variables, with random effects for fishing season and month.

[image: Structure of the data. Note that only 2010/ 2011 fishing season is complete]
How do I have to consider the relationship between the variables fishing season and month? Crossed effects or nested effects? 
From what I understood I have to consider crossed effects to model the relationship between fishing season and month because each month is repeated in fishing season... is this correct?
In each case, how do I code this???
Any suggestions?

I already found the answer here!!! Great answer indeed!! [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814#228814)

Comment: I was thinking that maybe is a better approach to consider month as a fixed effect rather than random one.... any opinion?

Comment: I would say that month should be a fixed effect.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for your advice and helping me with question edition!  ;)

Comment: So it would be something like `glmer(ifFishingEventPresent ~ a*b*c + month + (1|season), myData, family="binomial")`.